# How can we create Separate User Instance in Module in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii2

I had tried a lot to make a user login through my module. But always failed. Neither it shows a error nor it logged in to the application.
So far i have tried this.

My `module/moduleName/moduleName.php` init function is

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    // custom initialization code goes here

    Yii::$app->set('user', [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\module\modulesName\models\UserTable',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'loginUrl' => ['moduleName/default/login'],
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => 'module', 'httpOnly' => true],
        'idParam' => 'id', //this is important !
    ]);

    Yii::$app->set('session', [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
        'name' => '_adminSessionId',
    ]);
}
```

Now my `Loginform` in `app\module\moduleName\models\LoginForm` is

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\moduleName\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = UserTable::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Finally my model for login in `app\module\moduleName\models\UserTable` is

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\moduleName\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $fullName
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $authkey
 * @property string $accessToken
 * @property integer $authStatus

 */
class UserTable extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord  implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'usertable';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fullName', 'email', 'password'], 'required'],
            [['authStatus'], 'integer'],
            [['fullName', 'email', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['authkey', 'accessToken'], 'string', 'max' => 75],
            // [['fullName', 'password'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['fullName', 'password'], 'message' => 'The combination of Full Name and Password has already been taken.'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'fullName' => 'Full Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'authkey' => 'Authkey',
            'accessToken' => 'Access Token',
            'authStatus' => 'Auth Status',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */

     // User login Codes

     public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }



    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {

    return $this->password ===($password);
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token,$type=null)
    {
        return $this->accessToken;
    }
    public static function findbyUsername($uname)
    {

        return self::find()->where(['email' => $uname])->one();
    }
}
```

At the end my defaultcontroller in module is

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        var_dump('a');
        exit();
        return $this->render('index');
    } else {
      return $this->redirect(['login']);
    }
}

public function actionLogin()
{  
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**I do not know how the app is not logged in. I had tried for 3 days now and i did not get any solution on this problem. It neither shows me error nor it get logged in ? How can I log in to different user instance in yii2 ?**

Comment: Do not keep rules inside your database model. It is better if you create seperate model that validates and then save.

Answer (score 1):

Create seperate config.php in your module directory, then add It into inject it into your app. Here is code. 
Just confugure config.php as you want

```
return [
    'id' => 'api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    //....
    'components' => [
       //..
        'user' => [
           //....
        ]
    ],
];
```

In your module class just do like that.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    \Yii::configure($this, require __DIR__ . '/config.php');
}
```

Thats all.